# Adding additional tabs to Windows 10 notification areas

Tags: windows-10

In Windows 10 the notification areas have tabs added for different functionality.
For example, the battery notification area shows a 'Battery saver' and brightness tab as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcK8e.png)

[image]

Is there a way in which I can add additional tabs? If this is currently not possible, is it likely this functionality will be added?

Comment: Maybe this link is what you are looking for. You can add notifications of applications on the Notification Center - https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/5084/windows-10-tip-manage-notifications

Comment: @zain.ali: thanks for the link... unfortunately it is about notification settings. I am talking about the tabs at the e.g. the bottom of the 'Action Center' which say 'Bluetooth', 'Brightness', 'Airplane mode' etc.

Comment: I would add a picture, but i don't have enough rep to do that... It's a bit weird i can post questions but not add a picture :(.

Comment: @nluigi - The reputation requirement is to prevent user who might spam us from posting pictures.  Post a couple good questions or answers and you gain that ability.  You can also just upload the file the our image host and provide us the url.

Comment: @Ramhound: Ok that makes sense, I have edited the question with a link to the image